# Cant figure out how to write xpath in python in selinium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have got this piece of html code:

```html
<span class="amount ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="object.numberOfReactions !== null">41</span>
```

I want to acces the 41 number by using driver.find_elements_by_xpath,
my best try is
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//div[@ng.if='object.numberOfReactions !== null'])`but this gives an empty list []. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you change `//div` to `//span` and `@ng.if` to `@ng-if`?

Comment: Change `@ng.if` to `ng-if`.

Answer (score 2):

I know that there are multiple ways to write the xpath, but if you go to the html code, highlight it, and right click you should see options that allow you to copy the full xpath. I personally use this alot because it's really fast and easy to use
[image]

Comment: This is really not a good way to get XPaths. Most of the time you end up with a very brittle, very long XPath. It may be quick and easy but it's definitely not a good long term solution. The best way is to learn how to create the XPath yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Xpath is the property to element in browser. It doesn't mater which language we are using. XML path will be the same. [Use](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) to find xpath technique.

In python we can find element using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`